# How to create a servlet on the fly

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, servlets

For below URL's I receive a 404 error, this is fine since the URL's do not exist. Is it possible to create these servlets while the server is running before the error page is returned ?

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/test1
http://127.0.0.1:8888/test1/test2
```

I'm thinking perhaps to create a generic controller that intercepts all urls if the current servlet does not exist, then create it ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by `Spring` you mean `Spring MVC`, you could do something like this:

```
@Controller
public class YourController {
    @RequestMapping("/mappingA")
    public void methodA() {
        // (...)
    }

    @RequestMapping("/mappingB")
    public void methodB() {
        // (...)
    }

    // Catches all non-matched requests.
    @RequestMapping("/*")
    public void fake404(HttpServletRequest request) {
        var uri = request.getRequestURI();
        // (...)
    }
}
```